# How to escape a slash character in the preg_match pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a text like this:

```
line 1/1/1/2
```

The text after the line phrase is the parameter of a function, for example when I call `extractData('1/1/1/2' , 'The main text')`:

```
function extractData($line, $text)
{
    $pattern = "/line(\s+)$line/";
    if(preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
        // some code
    }

}
```

How can I escape the slash character in the pattern?
In other words, how should I write the pattern? (`$pattern = "/line(\s+)$line/";`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) function:

```
$pattern = '/line(\s+)' . preg_quote($line, '/') . '/';
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '1' in .... 
When I echo the pattern, it will be:   /line(\s+)1/1/1/1/

Comment: @DiariB look at the documentation of `preg_quote` that hsz provided a link to.

Comment: @DiariB Sorry, I've edited my answer - delimiter missing.

Comment: @hsz It's a magic function, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

To scape any character you use `\`, so to escape `/` you use `\/`

If you want to escape `\`, you need to escape it as `\\\`

Comment: The slash is in a variable and can't add any character to it

Comment: Then go with `preg_quote` function as mentioned by hsz

Answer (score 5):

[`\Q` and `\E`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) can be used to ignore regular expression metacharacters in the pattern as well.

```
$pattern = '~line(\s+)\Q' . $line . '\E~';
```

Comment: That's good to know! Still something new here :) Didn't find much [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) about it, but seems [to work](http://regex101.com/r/pI4xW2/1).

Comment: @Jonny5 [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), [regex-info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)